# Clicking/distortion when mixing two audio buffers

Tags: android, buffer, audiotrack, distortion

I'm developing an android audio app that requires simultaneous sounds.

I am trying to combine two sound buffers and am getting distortion at large amplitudes. 
This is what I am doing:

```
for(int i=0;i<data2.length;i+=2)
            {

                short buf1a = data[i+1];
                short buf2a = data[i];
                buf1a = (short)((buf1a & 0xff) << 8);
                buf2a = (short) (buf2a & 0xff);
                short buf1b = data2[i+1];
                short buf2b = data2[i];
                buf1b = (short) ((buf1b & 0xff) << 8);
                buf2b = (short) (buf2b & 0xff);

                short buf1c = (short) (buf1a + buf1b);
                short buf2c = (short) (buf2a + buf2b);

                short res = (short) (buf1c + buf2c);
        int res2 = res/2;
        res = (short)res2;
                data3[i]=(byte)res;
                data3[i+1]=(byte)(res>>8);

            }
```

The buffer is played using:

```
   AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(STREAM_MUSIC,44100,CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,dataSize,MODE_STATIC);
            at.write(data3,0,data3.length);
            int frames = data3.length/2; //2 bytes per frame.
            Log.d(TAG,"this is data length: "+data3.length);
            Log.d(TAG,"this is assumed frame number:"+frames);
            at.setLoopPoints(0,frames,3);
            at.play();
```

I followed the procedure outlined here almost exactly: [Java: Mixing two WAV files without introducing noise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856836/java-mixing-two-wav-files-without-introducing-noise?rq=1) .

The buffers data and data2 contain the data from the wav files I want to mix. When playing them on their own using AudioTrack they sound fine. Also, apart from the "high-amplitude-clicks", the mix sounds fine.

I assumed the problem was that the short values became too large for the largest amplitudes, but I don't know why, since I am dividing by 2. Really happy for any ideas.

Update: I output the mix to a wav and looked at it in Audacity. 
The top waveform below is my mix with the clicks. The bottom waveform is when Audacity mixes the two wav's and has no clicks.The clicks in my mix occur when the waveform touches the 'roof'/'floor' of the graph.
My mix appears to have a broader peak at these places. Still have not solved this. 
[image]
Update 2: 
This is what a problem area looks like up close. It looks like in the Audacity version it cuts to a highest/lowest value(floor/roof), but in my version it seems to jump to the other side and 'finish' its curve there.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code inspires me and finally I ended up facing the same problem. You're adding 16-byte short `buf1a`,`buf1b`,`buf2a`,`buf2b` values one to another and then casting the results to 16-byte short `buf1c` and `buf2c`. When the result of addition is lower then `-32,768` or greater then `32,767` a [loss conversation occours](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) becouse it exceeds `short` data type capacity...

an extract from Oracle docs:

> A narrowing primitive conversion may lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and range.

```
short buf1c = (short) (buf1a + buf1b);
short buf2c = (short) (buf2a + buf2b);
```

My simple modification :). This works perfectly without any distortion :

```
int buf1c = (buf1a + buf1b)/2;   
int buf2c = (buf2a + buf2b)/2;
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that solution is much better - I changed to your solution in my code now and works great. : )

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get rid of the clips by checking if large numbers suddenly changed sign. The code below added at the end of the for-loop seems to do the job and gives a result similar to what the audacity graph looks like in the question above.

```
        if(res>10000) //Avoid 'normal' cases where amplitude shifts from f.ex. 4 to -2, which we want to keep.
        {
            if((res*resPrevious)<0) //If the sign has changed suddenly for a large number, use the previous number.
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"res:"+res+"");
                res = resPrevious;
            }
        }
        if(res<-10000)
        {
            if((res*resPrevious)<0) //If the sign has changed suddenly for a large number, use the previous number.
            {
                res = resPrevious;
            }
        }
        resPrevious=res;
        data3[i] = (byte) res;
        data3[i + 1] = (byte) (res >> 8);
```