# How to add a sound while recording audio using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-mediarecorder

I am using MediaRecorder to record an audio and I want to add a sound when a button is clicked (without stopping the record) .
I currently play that sound when the user click on the button and it's annoying, do you have any suggestions please, thank you.

Comment: You mean you want to add sounds to recorder directly without actually playing the sound outside?

Comment: yes exactly, is that possible please?

Comment: Seems hard, but why don't you synthesize the sound effect after recording is end, to , like a temp file before playing the final output to the user?

Comment: thank you for your reply, but can you be more specific?

Comment: 1. Record audio normally and save it to 3gp file.
2. Convert 3gp to audio format like wav using libraries like ffmpeg.
3. Mix/merge your audio to the file.
4. Play the file.

Those steps are complicated but by now I don't know better way. Hope it helped.

Comment: Helpful Link for 1,2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5245723/8614565
3: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32856836/8614565

Comment: I'll publish those to answer if it helped.

Comment: I will try and post if it works